# Regular Expression Issue - Find numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using JavaScript to get a string from a field, in that field there would typically be;

"Width = 56 Void = 67"

What I need to do is identify the two digits which could be between a range of 1-440 and put them into two different fields which are

Field 1 = Width
Field 2 = Void

I've looked into regex which so far will let me identify what position a digit is in using the Search() method, but it doesn't really do what I require

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Have you considered breaking this up into two fields?  It will be easier to process and likely lead to fewer user input errors.

Comment: Once you get the numbers from the field, you will probably have to just use JS to validate their range and add them to the fields. Regex is really just for searching the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex's are greedy so you could do :

```
  var str = 'Width = 56 Void = 67';
  var a = str.match(/\d+/g);
```

Then you could check the values of a to see if they matched and if they are in your range of expected numbers, as now a is an array of ["56", 67"];

Comment: Worked great, thank you, now just to split the array and put the two values into the text fields

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
Width = (\d+) Void = (\d+)
```

Your JavaScript code to parse the string would look like this:

```
var regex = /Width = (\d+) Void = (\d+)/;
var match = regex.exec("Width = 56 Void = 67");
var field1 = parseInt(match[1], 10); // 56
var field2 = parseInt(match[2], 10); // 67
```

You'll want to add some error-checking, but that's the essential part.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! the previous answer did what was required but I will test this out later to see if it works, thanks

Comment: Thanks @Robert for catching my typo