# Find two numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, dynamics-crm-2013

This is a follow on from my previous question which can be found here

[Link For Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931798/regular-expression-issue-find-numbers-in-a-string)

I am posting a new question as the answer I got was correct, however my next question is how to take it a step further

Basically I have a string of data, within this data somewhere there will be the following;

```
Width = 70
Void = 40
```

The actual numbers there could be anything between 1-440.

From my previous question I found how to identify those two digits using regular expression and put them into separate fields, however, my issue now is that the string could contain for example

```
Part Number = 2353

Length = 3.3mm

Width = 70

Void = 35

Discount = 40%
```

My question is;

How do I identify only the Width + Void and put them into two separate fields, the answer in my previous question would not solve this issue as what would happen is in this example I would have an array of size 4 and I would simply select the 2nd and 3rd space.

This is not suitable for my issue as the length of array could vary from string to string therefore I need a way of identifying specifically

```
Width = ##
Void = ##
```

And from there be able to retrieve the digits individually to put into my separate fields

I am using JavaScript in CRM Dynamics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler option is to convert the whole string into an object and get what you need from that object.

```js
str = "Part Number = 2353\n" +
"Length = 3.3mm\n" +
"Width = 70\n" +
"Void = 35\n" +
"Discount = 40%\n";

data = {};

str.replace(/^(.+?)\s*=\s*(.+)$/gm, function(_, $1, $2) {
    data[$1] = $2;
});

alert(data['Width']);
```

Comment: Thanks all for the answers! I used this method in the end as it is as described a simple solution which worked perfectly!

Comment: Hi @georg - I'm currently having an issue getting the data retrieved into its correct field, the error is stating that only numbers or null can be accepted into the field. I have tried `var width = data['Width']);
var widthInt = new Number(width);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_width").setValue(widthInt);` However it has been unsucessful

Comment: @Sjharrison: `new Number` is not a number in javascript (sounds weird, but believe me). You need `Number(width)` or `parseInt(width,10)`.

Comment: Thank for your reply, that is weird! but worked a treat thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for matching input with `Width` and `Void` in any order:

```
/(\b(Width|Void) += *(\d+)\b)/
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vY6rC8/3)

Your variable names and values are available in captured groups.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer and for the link, that really helped to understand it better! My question now is where would I go from here? The code in the link showed that it has a match but how would I get just the width number to go into one field and the void number to go into another? Thanks @anubhava

Comment: Any special reason why you've separated the options? `(\b(Width|Void)\s*?=\s*?(\d+)\b)` would yield the same result - http://regex101.com/r/iT0hL9/1

Comment: As I wrote in my comment those values are available in resulting match array after calling `String#match` using above regex.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks so much, yes that's shorter. I edited my answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Width\s+=\s+(\d+)|Void\s+=\s+(\d+)
```

You can try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/31

```
var re = /Width\s+=\s+(\d+)|Void\s+=\s+(\d+)/igm;
var str = 'Part Number = 2353\n\nLength = 3.3mm\n\nWidth = 70\n\nVoid = 35\n\nDiscount = 40%';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```